# How do I filter categorical data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the information of the data

```
    sex     age         race        
    Male    0.204082    Hispanic    
    Male    0.122449    African-American    
    Female  0.163265    African-American    
    Male    0.081633    African-American    
    Male    0.530612    African-American
```

```
African-American    2968
Caucasian           1969
Hispanic             502
Other                294
Asian                 26
Native American       13
Name: race, dtype: int64
```

I want to basically remove Native American and Asian from the dataset, and this is what I did:

```
df_train_val_scaled = df_train_val_scaled[df_train_val_scaled["race"] != "Native American" & df_train_val_scaled["race"] != "Asian"]
```

which produced the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

So I tried the following

```
df_train_val_scaled = df_train_val_scaled[df_train_val_scaled["race"] not in ["Native American", "Asian"]]
```

But it also produces errors

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `df_train_val_scaled[(df_train_val_scaled["race"] != "Native American") & (df_train_val_scaled["race"] != "Asian")]`?

Comment: That works! Thanks @wwnde

Comment: When you have two or more filtering conditions, don't forget to wrap each of the conditions by parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to check whether every element is (not) in a given list with `~df['race'].isin(['a', 'b', c'])`. Here's an example:

```py
from io import StringIO as sio

data = sio("""
 sex     age         race        
    Male    0.204082    Hispanic    
    Male    0.122449    African-American    
    Female  0.163265    African-American    
    Male    0.081633    African-American    
    Male    0.530612    African-American
""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+').astype({'race': 'category'})

df_train_val_scaled = df[~df["race"].isin(["Native American", "Asian"])]
df_train_val_scaled
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter a DataFrame based on any column values using the isin() function which returns a boolean Series which can be passed to the DataFrame to get the filtered results.
You can pass this boolean Series to the DataFrame which then returns a DataFrame after filtering the rows based on the boolean Series passed.

```
import pandas as pd

people = {
    'sex': ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
    'age': [0.204082, 0.163265, 0.204082, 0.214082, 0.204082],
    'race': ['Hispanic', 'African-American', 'Asian', 'Asian', 'Asian']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(people)

filter_ = ~df['race'].isin(['African-American', 'Asian'])

print(filter_)

# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4    False
# Name: race, dtype: bool

df_filtered = df[filter_]
print(df_filtered)

#     sex       age      race
# 0  Male  0.204082  Hispanic
```